# Finding Groups of Rearranged Strings from a txt With Strings on Seperate Lines

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, anagram

What I would like to do is take an input txt file of any length which looks like this

```
bob
joe
obb
oej
```

and produce an output txt file which sorts groups of re-arranged words on a single line and alphabetically in an output txt file.

```
bob obb
joe oej
```

Here is what I have attempted so far where `args[0]` is a file called input.txt passed in the command line.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]):
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    List<char[]> anagrams = new ArrayList();

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        char[] arr = line.toCharArray();

        if (containsAnagram(anagrams, line))
            continue;
        else anagrams.add(line);

        while (scan2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line2 = scan2.nextLine();
   
            if (isAnagram(arr, line2))
                fileContent2+=” ”+line2;
        }
        fileContent+=fileContent2+”\n”;
    }
}

private static boolean isAnagram(char[] arr, String line) {
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(line).contains(arr(i))
            break;
        if (i=arr.length-1)
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error in your code? If so, what is it. Is your output incorrect, if so, could you please tell us the actual output?

Comment: Sort all characters of string and store all anagrams in a map. Map key is the sorted state of the string and it's list has all original strings who are anagrams of the current key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a compact way to achieve what you need using java.nio Files , Streams and a Function:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         // (1)
        List<String> input = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path to your input file"));
        // (2)
        Function<String,String> func = s -> Pattern.compile("")                     
                                                    .splitAsStream(s)
                                                    .sorted()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
        // (3)
        List<String> output = input.stream()                                       
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(func))
                                    .values()
                                    .stream()                
                                    .map(list -> list.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
                                    .sorted()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        // (4)
        Files.write(Paths.get("path to your output file"), output, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

1. Read all lines of input file into a list
2. Define a function which accepts a string and returns a string with
   sorted chars of the input, e.g bob -> bbo
3. group your input list by above function, stream over the values of
   the resulting map maping each list to a space delimited string to
   form a line of output text, collect all strings to an output list
4. write to output file

Comment: Nice answer ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]):
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    List<char[]> anagrams = new ArrayList();

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file);
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        char[] arr = line.toCharArray();

        if (containsAnagram(anagrams, line))
            continue;
        else anagrams.add(line);

        while (scan2.hasNextLine()) {
            String line2 = scan2.nextLine();
   
            if (isAnagram(arr, line2))
                fileContent2+=” ”+line2;
        }
        fileContent+=fileContent2+”\n”;
    }
}

private static boolean isAnagram(char[] arr, String line) {
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (!Arrays.asList(line).contains(arr(i))
            break;
        if (i=arr.length-1)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private static boolean containsAnagram(List<char[]> list, String line) {
    for (char[] anagram : list) {
        if (isAnagram(anagram, line))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```